# Query optimization in associated models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, rails-activerecord

I have a `User` model

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :skills
  has_one :profile
end
```

`Profile` table has two columns named, `age` & `experience`

Now, I've a search form where the parameters are passed are:

```
params[:skill_ids] = [273,122,233]
params[:age] = "23"
params[:experience] = "2"
```

I've to search through all the users where user's skills meet any of the `params[:skill_ids]` and also from the user's profile, their age and experience.

Do I have to go through a loop like:

```
users = []
User.all.each do |user|
  if (user.skills.collect{|s| s.id} & params[:skill_ids] ) > 0
     // skip other  parts
     users << user
  end
end
```

or, any of you have any better solution?

Comment: Are you sure it's `has_many :skills`? Shouldn't it be `has_and_belongs_to_many :skills`? Otherwise, skills cannot be shared between instances of User.

Comment: Yes, `user has_many skills`, I know it's little bit strange. But the skills are not predefined or shared between the other users. every user have their individual skills and they are not shared to others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because your skills belong to exactly one user, you could first fetch all users belonging to the skill ids provided and filter them by the other criteria:

```
matching_users = User.includes(:skills, :profile)
  .where(["skills.id in (?) AND profile.age = ? AND profile.experience = ?", 
          params[:skill_ids],
          params[:age].to_i, 
          params[:experience].to_i]
        )
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
@users = User.includes(:skills).where(["skills.id in (?)", params[:skill_ids]]).all
```